# Obter valor expressão

Tags: javascript

No meu codigo javascript utilizo este expressao para fazer um calculo para obter valor de um grafico com a posicao do rato (posY). 460 é a posição do meu eixo, e o maximo e minimo dos valores do grafico do eixo y.

```
value =  ((460 - posY) * (maxtemp-txtmintemp)/(460-60)+txtmintemp);
```

A partir desta expressão queria obter a posição Y, e tenho o valor, como por exemplo isto:

```
10.30 =  ((460 - posY) * (maxtemp-txtmintemp)/(460-60)+txtmintemp);
```

Como posso calcular esta expressão, isolando o posY, que é o valor que quero obter.

Comment: Quais são os valores de `maxtemp` e `txtmintemp`?

Comment: São os valores minimo e maximo do meu eixo y. Neste caso o minimo é 2 e o max é 96.

Comment: Utilizando isso, penso chegar ao valor que pretendo. http://es.solvemymath.com/calculadoras/algebra/resolver_ecuaciones.php

Comment: E [isto](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%3D%28460-y%29*%28m-n%29%2F%28460-60%29%2Bn+for+y) que quer? Sendo que `m` e `maxTemp`, `n` e `txtMinTemp` e `x` e o `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto é um exercício de algebra. Trocando as posições consegue isolar-se o posY. Daria assim:

```
posY = - ((((10.30 - txtmintemp) * (460 - 60)) / (maxtemp - txtmintemp)) - 460);
```

Testando:

```js
var maxtemp = 96;
var txtmintemp = 2;
var posY = -((((10.30 - txtmintemp) * (460 - 60)) / (maxtemp - txtmintemp)) - 460);
alert('posY dá: ' + posY);
var original = ((460 - posY) * (maxtemp - txtmintemp) / (460 - 60) + txtmintemp);
original = Math.round(original * 100) / 100
alert('verificação: ' + (10.30 == original));
```